# Speed unit converter

Tags: java, beginner, android, converting, event-handling

I'm basically a newbie in android app developing. So I'm not sure if this is the right way to write these codes. I have made an app called "Zconverter". It has 9 fragments and the code i m showing here is the smallest of them all. All the fragments have the same type of code. This app works just fine but i m not sure if this is the best way to write this.

```
public class Speed extends Fragment {
    public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container , Bundle savedInstanceState){
    final ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.speed_fragment, container, false);


    final EditText editMilesHour = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.editMilesHour);
    final EditText editfeetsec = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.editfeetsec);
    final EditText editMeterSec = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.editMeterSec);
    final EditText editKmHour = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.editKmHour);
    final EditText editKnot = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.editKnot);

    TextView textSpeed = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textSpeed);
    TextView textKmHour = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textKmHour);
    TextView textKnot = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textKnot);
    TextView textMilesHour = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textMilesHour);
    TextView textfeetsec = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textfeetsec);
    TextView textMeterSec = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textMeterSec);

    Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "CoffeeHouse.ttf");
    textMeterSec.setTypeface(font);
    textMilesHour.setTypeface(font);
    textKnot.setTypeface(font);
    textKmHour.setTypeface(font);
    textfeetsec.setTypeface(font);
    textSpeed.setTypeface(font);


    editMeterSec.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if(hasFocus){
                Button buttonConvertSpeed = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.buttonConvertSpeed);
                buttonConvertSpeed.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                                          @Override
                                                          public void onClick(View v) {
                                                              double MeterSec = Double.valueOf(editMeterSec.getText().toString());
                                                              double MilesHour = MeterSec * 2.23694;
                                                              editMilesHour.setText(String.valueOf(MilesHour));
                                                              double feetsec = MeterSec * 3.28084;
                                                              editfeetsec.setText(String.valueOf(feetsec));
                                                              double KmHour = MeterSec * 3.6;
                                                              editKmHour.setText(String.valueOf(KmHour));
                                                              double Knot = MeterSec * 1.94384;
                                                              editKnot.setText(String.valueOf(Knot));

                                                          }

                                                      }
                );

            }else{

            }

        }
    });


    editMilesHour.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if(hasFocus){
                Button buttonConvertSpeed = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.buttonConvertSpeed);
                buttonConvertSpeed.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                                          @Override
                                                          public void onClick(View v) {
                                                              double MilesHour6 = Double.valueOf(editMilesHour.getText().toString());
                                                              double MeterSec6 = MilesHour6 * 0.44704;
                                                              editMeterSec.setText(String.valueOf(MeterSec6));
                                                              double feetsec6 = MilesHour6 * 1.46667;
                                                              editfeetsec.setText(String.valueOf(feetsec6));
                                                              double KmHour6 = MilesHour6 * 1.60934;
                                                              editKmHour.setText(String.valueOf(KmHour6));
                                                              double Knot6 = MilesHour6 * 0.868976;
                                                              editKnot.setText(String.valueOf(Knot6));

                                                          }

                                                      }
                );

            }else{

            }
        }
    });

    editfeetsec.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if(hasFocus){
                Button buttonConvertSpeed = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.buttonConvertSpeed);
                buttonConvertSpeed.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                                          @Override
                                                          public void onClick(View v) {
                                                              double feetsec7 = Double.valueOf(editfeetsec.getText().toString());
                                                              double MeterSec7 = feetsec7 * 0.3048;
                                                              editMeterSec.setText(String.valueOf(MeterSec7));
                                                              double MilesHour7 = feetsec7 * 0.681818;
                                                              editMilesHour.setText(String.valueOf(MilesHour7));
                                                              double KmHour7 = feetsec7 * 1.09728;
                                                              editKmHour.setText(String.valueOf(KmHour7));
                                                              double Knot7 = feetsec7 * 0.592484;
                                                              editKnot.setText(String.valueOf(Knot7));

                                                          }

                                                      }
                );

            }else{

            }
        }
    });

    editKmHour.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if(hasFocus){
                Button buttonConvertSpeed = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.buttonConvertSpeed);
                buttonConvertSpeed.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                                          @Override
                                                          public void onClick(View v) {
                                                              double KmHour8 = Double.valueOf(editKmHour.getText().toString());
                                                              double MeterSec8 = KmHour8 * 0.277778;
                                                              editMeterSec.setText(String.valueOf(MeterSec8));
                                                              double MilesHour8 = KmHour8 * 0.621371;
                                                              editMilesHour.setText(String.valueOf(MilesHour8));
                                                              double feetsec8 = KmHour8 * 0.911344;
                                                              editfeetsec.setText(String.valueOf(feetsec8));
                                                              double Knot8 = KmHour8 * 0.539957;
                                                              editKnot.setText(String.valueOf(Knot8));

                                                          }

                                                      }
                );

            }else{

            }
        }
    });

    editKnot.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if(hasFocus){
                Button buttonConvertSpeed = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.buttonConvertSpeed);
                buttonConvertSpeed.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                                          @Override
                                                          public void onClick(View v) {
                                                              double Knot9 = Double.valueOf(editKnot.getText().toString());
                                                              double MeterSec9 = Knot9 * 0.514444;
                                                              editMeterSec.setText(String.valueOf(MeterSec9));
                                                              double MilesHour9 = Knot9 * 1.15078;
                                                              editMilesHour.setText(String.valueOf(MilesHour9));
                                                              double feetsec9 = Knot9 * 1.68781;
                                                              editfeetsec.setText(String.valueOf(feetsec9));
                                                              double KmHour9 = Knot9 * 1.852;
                                                              editKmHour.setText(String.valueOf(KmHour9));

                                                          }

                                                      }
                );

            }else{

            }
        }
    });



    return rootView;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to CR! I suggest you make your title tell a bit more about what the fragments do; *everyone* on this site is looking for ways to make their code better, saying you want that in your title is somewhat redundant ;) also that last closing brace isn't included in the code block; please make sure your indentation matches that in your IDE (select the relevant code in your post, and then Ctrl+K).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things that can be improved:

1. Error handling. Your code does not handle the case when a text does not represent a valid `double`. It would be nice to have some error handling(for instance, you could show an error message in this case). For instance, this line of code:

   ```
   double MeterSec = Double.valueOf(editMeterSec.getText().toString());
   ```

   will fail with `NumberFormatException` if `editMeterSec.getText().toString()` is not a valid representation of a `double` number. You can do it by catching this exception:

   ```
   try {
       double MeterSec = Double.valueOf(editMeterSec.getText().toString());
       ...
   } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
      // Show an error message or do something else.
   }
   ```
2. "Magic" constants. It is not good to use such numbers as `3.28084` or `3.6` directly in your code because their meaning is not clear. You should create variables with meaningful names to hold these constants. For instance, you could have a

   ```
   private static final KILOMETERS_PER_HOUR_TO_METERS_PER_SECOND_RATIO = 3.6;
   ```

   and then use it for the conversion between different units of speed.
3. Empty `else` blocks are redundant. Just get rid of them.

   ```
   if (predicate) {
       // Do something.
   } else {
       // An empty block.
   }
   ```

   should become

   ```
   if (predicate) {
       // Do something.
   }
   ```
4. Whitespaces. It is conventional to have a whitespace after `if`, `for` and `while` keywords, before and after curly brackets.
5. Variable naming. Non-static, non-final variables' names should start with a lowercase letter(and different words are separated using camelCase). It is not consistent in your code: `textSpeed`, for instance, follows this convention, but `MeterSec` or `feetsec` violates it.
6. Design of your class. Having one huge method that does everything is a bad practice. Moreover, the entire `Speed` class does too many things: it handles GUI and the conversion logic at the same time. I would recommend creating a separate utility class that converts speed units into each other. Current design makes your code very hard to test.
7. Avoiding code duplication. Several event listeners contain the same code:

   ```
   new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
       @Override
       public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
           if (hasFocus) {
               Button buttonConvertSpeed = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.buttonConvertSpeed);
               buttonConvertSpeed.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                                         @Override
                                                         public void onClick(View v) {
                                                             // Do something.   
                                                         }
               });
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   Instead of using local anonymous classes and duplicate code, you can create a class that implements the `View.OnFocusChangeListener` interface so that you can reuse it(it can have a constructor that takes a `Runnable` interface to customize the behavior of the `onClick` method). In general, you should try and improve the modularity of your code.

Comment: Your answer was really helpful but I really didn't understand your opinion no. 7....how would i customize the behavior of onClick method?? if u could show me an example how to do so, it would be really helpful. :)

Comment: @RsqZmn Something like this: http://pastebin.com/hfDF2kxb.